# Google result removal

Tags: search-engine

I'm really sorry if I'm asking this in wrong place, but I was always wondering:

- Is there a way to ask google to remove a specific result/range of results/specific criteria from their database?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. However, you can search yourself and ask the linked sites to remove your name and connected pages.

Actually, there is a way, but you probably won't be able to do it. If you present Google with a court order to remove it (this requires a lawsuit against the owner of the site, and the court deems it to be slander), Google will blacklist the site from their search results.